# Apdex - Mobile users

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, loading

I'm using both New Relic and Ruxit. They are using Apdex as measurement on the users load time.

The problem I'm having is that the majority of my users are mobile users and I believe that its nearly impossible to achieve a excellent Apdex rating on a normal site with a 3G mobile connection. Even 4G have pretty bad response time.

So you can change Apdex. The question is however... What should you change it to? Is there any standard score for mobile users?

Or am I completely wrong and should really think about what I just wrote...

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Philip. Can you please clarify what New Relic, Ruxit, and Apdex are, what they do, and what you're hoping to accomplish with them?

Comment: Cannot answer. On hold. No, it's not impossible. It's just really hard and tedious. You have to use a lot of caching. Consider using a CDN. Also consider making your site Javascript rich, with many AJAX calls which transfer JSON and reduces the payload of the responses. The site will load once, and then future interactions will be AJAX calls. You can simulate slow networks in Chrome dev console with mobile view. Use Google PageSpeed insights to get lots of tips on how to speed it up. Remember, try to get the server response down, then work on the total client response time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** You adjust the Apdex response times to suit your needs. You want response thresholds to be low enough to give you sufficient resolution of your system performance, without having it so low that you start receiving too many false alarms.

---

Here's what New Relic says about Apdex:

> Apdex is a measure of response time based against a set threshold. It measures the ratio of satisfactory response times to unsatisfactory response times. The response time is measured from an asset request to completed delivery back to the requestor.
>
> The application owner defines a response time threshold T. All responses handled in T or less time satisfy the user.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/new-relic-apm/apdex/apdex-measuring-user-satisfaction

According to a Sales Engineer from New Relic, you should absolutely adjust the response time threshold T to suit your app. The biggest use for Apdex isn't so much the Apdex Score itself, but setting it up so the system can notify you during times of heavy usage so you can look into issues, and potentially scale up your servers to meet increase demands.

#### What should you set "T" to?

They recommend you monitor response times for ~ a week. Then look at your data to determine the average response time for "normal" usage. The "T threshold" should be set to be slightly above normal usage. This will give you maximum resolution for detecting issues with your system. However, you should be mindful that the lower the threshold, the more likely you are to receive false alarms. So set your threshold by balancing these two things.